# How to do `articles.includes(:tags).where('lower(tags.name) = ?', x)` in Rails associations?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, associations, eager-loading

I have this working query:

```
def articles_tagged_with(x)
  user.articles.includes(:tags).all.select do |article|
    article.tags.any? do |tag|
      tag.name.downcase == x
    end
  end
end
```

How can I change that to move more of it into SQL directly?

I tried this:

```
def articles_tagged_with(x)
  user.articles.includes(:tags)
    .where('lower(tags.name) = ?', x)
    .all
end
```

But I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
  PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tags"
  LINE 1: ...rticles"."user_id" = $1 AND (lower(tags.name)...
```

What am I missing? How do I do that?

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr :name
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_associations, dependent:  :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :tag_associations
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end
```

Comment: You need to include a reference to the association so that rails knows to run this as a single query rather than 2. e.g. (`.includes(:tags).references(:tags)`). This is not necessary if rails can determine it has to include this table by interrogating the where finders hash but since you are using a string as an argument to where rails cannot determine the needed reference. `joins(:tags).includes(:tags)` will also work as an INNER JOIN

Comment: Still get `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tags"` if I do `user.articles.joins(:tags).includes(:tags).where('lower(tags.name) = ?', x).all` or even `user.articles.includes(:tags).references(:tags).where('lower(tags.name) = ?', x).all`.

Comment: We would need to see your schema because now the only reason that would occur is that the table is not called "tags" but you are referring to it as tags in  `'lower(tags.name) = ?'`

Comment: @engineersmnky added the models to help. Thanks.

Comment: Is something with [Arel](https://www.scimedsolutions.com/blog/arel-part-i-case-insensitive-searches-with-partial-matching) necessary?

Comment: We can use Arel as follows `where(Tag.arel_table[:name].lower.eq(x))` which may resolve the issue because it removes the need to know the table name. That being said given your setup I cannot understand (nor would I be able to reproduce) your issue because `joins` will add the table to the FROM clause as an INNER JOIN and `includes`/`references` will add the table to the FROM clause as a LEFT OUTER JOIN so either way the table will be in the FROM clause. As a pure aside the `all` is not needed in either case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to make `x` a string like so:

```
where('lower(tags.name) = ?', "#{x}")
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, it seems `%` works only if we're checking with `like` or `ilike`

Comment: Nope, same error, still getting `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tags"`. The value `x` is already a string in my case.

Comment: Could you try this `where(tags: {name: x})`. unless of course you've tried that already or you explicitly want to use raw `SQL`.

Comment: I need it to use `lower(name)` though, can you do that with `where(tags: {lower(name): x})` somehow?

Comment: I mean you could try, otherwise, you could just use a symbol as `where(tags: {[name.downcase]: x})` haven't test this or even written it before.

Comment: It feels like you're just guessing. I appreciate it though.

Comment: Oh sorry, not at all, but the update to your question helps. It seems your `Tag` model needs to have a relationship in there `has_many: articles, through: tag_associations` and `has_many: tag_associations`, it also seems your `TagAssosciation` model is missing in your question, if there isn't any you may have to add it. because the through association will look for that model to relate the models.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the `tags` table is joined in the query - one way to do that is to join it explicitly.

```
def articles_tagged_with(x)
  user.articles.joins(:tags)
    .where('lower(tags.name) = ?', x)
end
```

This approach is most efficient, but will not eager load/preload the `tags` associated with the articles in the resulting activerecord objects, potentially causing a 1+N problem if you're calling `article.tags` later on.

If you want tags to be eager loaded, you can explicitly tell `.includes` that you're using the `tags` table so that `.includes` will choose the correct approach and add the `tags` table to the SQL queries. You can do this by adding `.references(:tags)`.

```
def articles_tagged_with(x)
  user.articles.includes(:tags).references(:tags)
    .where('lower(tags.name) = ?', x)
end
```

ActiveRecord knows to do this for you when you query the tags table in a structured way (e.g. with `.where(tags: {name: x})`) but it isn't smart enough to infer it when you give it a string "where" clause.

Another option is to just call `.eager_load` directly (which is what `.includes` will use under the hood). This is identical to using `.includes(:tags).references(:tags)`.

```
def articles_tagged_with(x)
  user.articles.eager_load(:tags)
    .where('lower(tags.name) = ?', x)
end
```

The reason it wasn't joined with `.includes` (but sometimes will be!) is due to how `.includes` chooses between `eager_load` and `preload` approaches for loading the data. [Here's](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes) a great article explaining the differences.